# Should I have flagged a "question" that should have been a blog post as "unclear what you're asking"?

Tags: discussion

I came across this "question": 
[Java + JAX-RS + JSON + JPA 2 Sample on GAE and Restlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357847/java-jax-rs-json-jpa-2-sample-on-gae-and-restlet), which is not so much a question as a blog post. This is noted both by the asker and another commenter.

Since (as far as I can tell) it's clearly not a question and not a good fit for Stack Overflow, I flagged it as "unclear what you're asking." According to my flagging history, this flag was declined. Nothing changed on the question to indicate that it should be kept.

Was my flagging incorrect? How should I handle questions like this in the future?

Comment: [Ken White's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357847/java-jax-rs-json-jpa-2-sample-on-gae-and-restlet#comment46862040_24357847) is your answer. In it's current state you are correct to flag it or vote to close. The OP needs to change it to a separate question and answer then it'll be fine. Or someone else could do it as that author hasn't been seen since September 2014.

Comment: @slugster I notice that it's been put on hold for the same reason that I flagged it, but my flag was still marked as declined. Is that a fact of life or something that I can correct?

Comment: It's a fact of life - don't be concerned about one declined flag. If you keep getting your flags declined then you should be concerned.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That question was really struggling to get the attention it needed to be closed. It went to the Close Votes queue *four times*. Three of those times the task ended up invalidated because the close vote/flag that sent it there aged away. One of those times it actually did get viewed but, unfortunately, by the wrong people, all of whom didn't actually evaluate the question and just chose to leave it open (and thus declining your perfectly valid flag).

Comment: Don't you just love review.

Comment: Maybe he should have done Q&A style. Perhaps it could be useful to someone, but it's not entirely clear what problem he is solving (he uses the word "solution" near the beginning, but never the word "problem"). Closing actually seems reasonable for once (although downvoting a new user who merely wants to share his knowledge possibly less so).

Comment: @canon: I don't see a "too localized" option in my close vote box.

Comment: @canon: There are a lot of questions that are "too localized." However, sometimes it turns out that one of them is the exact problem you're having, at which point it makes a lot of sense to keep them around.

Comment: Sometimes sanity wins over rules, at least for a while.  If a question is useful to people, I want it there even if it isn't a good "Fit".  A lot of times I find the most useful answers on SO in the deleted category.  This sounds a little like a case of Juror's prudence where the jury is allowed to go against the law if the law is simply wrong...